# Why does PHP mail() function not sending mail?

Tags: php

I have been trying to make this script where the user info from a form will be sent over to someone by mail and also the same information will save that exact information in a .txt file.

```
if (isset($_POST['enquire'])) {

    //set variables
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $mobile = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];   
    $cust_message = $_POST['message'];


//set mail vairables
    $to = "someone@example.com";
    $subject = "Enquiry on ABC";

//message   
    $message = ' //proper HTML is used removed here to make this code shorter
        <h1>New Enquiry on ABC!</h1> 
        <table cellspacing="0" style="border: 1px solid whitesmoke; max-width: 500px;width:50%;"> 
            <tr> <th>Name:</th><td>'.$name.'</td> </tr> 
            <tr> <th>Email:</th><td>'.$email.'</td> </tr> 
            <tr> <th>Mobile:</th><td>'.$mobile.'</td> </tr> 
            <tr> <th>Message:</th><td>'.$cust_message.'</td> </tr>
        </table>';

//set headers   
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "From: enquiry@example.com" . "\r\n". "CC: someone_else@example.com";

//shoot the mail
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

// write to file
    $myfile = fopen("leads.txt", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $txt = "Name: ".$_POST['name']."\r\n"."Email: ".$_POST['email']."\r\n"."Number: ".$_POST['phone']."\r\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    fclose($myfile);

}
```

One weird thing is I am not receiving any email and nither I am seeing any error Log!

Comment: run `mail` function in a variable. Let's say `$sendmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);`<br>
Then we can add the bellow part and can get a error message. It will help us to resolve the issue.
`if (!$sendmail) {
    $errorMessage = error_get_last()['message'];
}`

Comment: After the above modifications, run the script. It ill display an error. Post it here.

Comment: Hi, I tried the above script but I am not able to see any error on the page and also not in the error log. Mail is not yet received by anyone!

Comment: are you sending this email on localhost or on an online server?

Comment: I am using server hosted on Bigrock.in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a Buggy HTML form.

So in the HTML  has a submit button which did not have any name="" attribute. Hence isset() was not true and the script didn't work.

Thank you all for the taking time to answer it.